# .trigger() not triggering autosize event

Tags: javascript, jquery, eventtrigger, autosize

Hi I have a project using [autosize](http://www.jacklmoore.com/autosize/) text fields, these field need to be updated using an 'autosize:update' trigger if the field is edited by a script, but I'm having some trouble getting this to work. If I try entering:

```
$('.auto-size').trigger('autosize:update')
```

Into the console when the update needs to happen, nothing happens and I'm not sure why?

I'm pretty new to javascript/jquery so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you try the code that is almost at the top of the page you're linking to, where it uses `dispatchEvent` instead to trigger that exact same event.

Comment: I did try that but I also couldn't get it to work that way, I assumed that method and the way I've posted in the question would be functionally equivalent, since they're both supposed to be triggering the event.

Comment: jQuery's `trigger()` **only** triggers events bound with jQuery, so the plugin has to be using jQuery for those custom events, and it does seem strange that if that was the case, they would be using `dispatchEvent` in the docs ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As reported in the documentation you can use:

```
autosize.update($('.auto-size'));
```

or you can use:

```
   var evt = document.createEvent('Event');
   evt.initEvent('autosize:update', true, false);
   $('.auto-size').get(0).dispatchEvent(evt);
```

An example:

```js
// initialiaze the field
autosize($('.auto-size'));


// add new text to textarea and update!
$('#myBtn').on('click', function(e) {
  var ele = $('.auto-size');
  ele.text(ele.text() + 'This is a new line.\n');

  autosize.update(ele);
  
  // Dispatch a 'autosize:update' event to trigger a resize:
  //var evt = document.createEvent('Event');
  //evt.initEvent('autosize:update', true, false);
  //$('.auto-size').get(0).dispatchEvent(evt);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/jackmoore/autosize/master/dist/autosize.min.js"></script>


<textarea class="auto-size"></textarea>

<button id="myBtn">Click Me</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

if autosize:update is a css property, it probably is but i can't find it online. But if it IS,

```
$(".auto-size").trigger(function(){
    $(".auto-size").css("autosize","update");
});
```

Comment: what's autosize:update? and can you gimme the whole script?